# Redis saves wrong value

Tags: laravel, redis, broadcast

When I `dd` the `message` property in my event is gives me the correct value.

[image]

```
redis.psubscribe('*', (pattern, count) => {
  // ...
});

redis.on('pmessage', (pattern, channel, message) => {
  message = JSON.parse(message);

  console.log(message.data.message);
});
```

And when I fire my event, `redis.on()` produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: looks like you have $visible set in your model class, which dd do not care ... that's why you are getting two different sets of results

Comment: @SirGalahad did not change something related to `visible` in my model class